# Jquery assertion and expect for Codemirror editor

Tags: jquery, html, css, codemirror

I am a newbie to javascript trying to execute code inside codemirror editor. I am writing course for html and css with preview and check if the code is correct.  I have searched many sites couldn't find solution.  Where do I begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this tool to start with: http://jsfiddle.net/DXk3e/1/

You can see and resize 4 window panes for a live update.

To download the full code, just append `show/` to the url, like: `jsfiddle.net/DXk3e/1/show/`